# Is gravitational time dilation considered as a repulsive force (from the point of view of a far-away observer)?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, black-holes, observers

An infalling particle does never reach the event horizon of a Schwarzschild black hole, from the point of view of the reference frame of a far-away observer. Gravitational time dilation slows down its velocity, the particle needs more and more time for a given distance (v = s/t). Can we talk here of a repulsive gravitational force and/ or a repulsive gravitational effect?

Comment: @safesphere: I do not ask for more than your comment "the repulsive effect of the horizon is self evident." This is surprising for me because I only learnt about attractive effects of gravity, it might be interesting to read this in some literature.

Answer (score 4):

No. General relativity doesn't define gravity as a force at all. The definition of inertial motion in GR is a timelike geodesic, which is the motion of a test particle that is not affected by any nongravitational forces. Your infalling particle travels along a geodesic and is not subject to any force.

> Gravitational time dilation slows down its velocity, the particle needs more and more time for a given distance (v = s/t).

This is wrong. You can't explain this effect using special-relativistic time dilation, i.e., kinematic time dilation. Kinematic time dilation doesn't make objects' velocities appear to be smaller. If a proton is moving away from me at 0.97c, then in special relativity by definition this is a statement about what velocity I observe, in my frame of reference. There is no other frame of reference that would be relevant.

What prevents you from observing the horizon of a black hole can be interpreted as gravitational time dilation, not kinematic time dilation.

Comment: Your answer is off-topic. I never mentioned velocity-related time dilation of special relativity, and in my last sentence I did not insist on the term "force" in order to respect the fact that strictly speaking general relativity does not describe gravity as a force.

Answer (score 1):

> An infalling particle does never reach the event horizon of a Schwarzschild black hole, from the point of view of the reference frame of a far-away observer.

Yes but the particle reaches the event horizon from its point of view.

> Gravitational time dilation slows down its velocity.

> the particle needs more and more time for a given distance (v = s/t).

How do you define t here?Why is the time experienced by the observer more correct than the experienced time  of the falling object?

> Can we talk here of a repulsive gravitational force and/ or a repulsive gravitational effect?

1)Only the stress-energy tensor describes how spacetime is curved nothing else!

2)Gravity isnt a force.

Comment: **t** is the time of the far-away observer. I do not weigh the point of view of the far-away observer against the point of view of the infalling observer, both have _raison d'être_. But I am talking here of the point of view of the far-away observer.

Comment: I agree that you must refer to the stress-energy tensor for this question. What does the stress-energy tensor say about the repulsive effect of gravitational time dilation?

Comment: @safesphere: we are talking about the outside region near the event horizon where the stress energy tensor is not zero. It might be interesting to know if the energy stress tensor includes some distinction of both opposed gravitational phenomena.

Answer (score -1):

If we apply a force to an observer then that observer "feels" the force. For example an astronaut floating freely in space is weightless, i.e. they feel no force, but if we accelerate them by strapping a rocket motor to them then they feel the force applied to them by the rocket motor. More prosaically, if you are in a sports car speeding round a corner you feel the force the car exerts on you to provide your centripetal acceleration. Colloquially these forces tend to be described as the [g-forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force).

The force the observer feels is related to the proper acceleration of the observer by the simple equation:

$$ |\mathbf F| = m a $$

where $m$ is the rest mass of the observer and $a$ is the [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) of the observer. This is of course just Newton's second law, but some caution is needed as the equation applies only in the rest frame of the observer.

The importance of this is that the proper acceleration is a scalar invariant i.e. everyone, regardless of their coordinate systems, will agree on the value of the proper acceleration. This means we have an unambiguous way to tell if a force is being applied to the observer. We simply compute their proper acceleration and if it is non-zero a force is being applied. Conversely if it is zero no force is being applied.

For the observer falling into a black hole their proper acceleration is zero all through their trajectory. That means the force on them is zero, and this is the reason why we say gravity is not a force. From your perspective, standing far from the black hole, you see the falling observer slowing to a halt as they approach the horizon. But if you compute their proper acceleration you will find it remains zero even as they are slowing. From the argument above that means no repulsive force is being applied to them, so no the time dilation is not a repulsive force.

You are of course free to consider gravity a force - after all Newton did - and in that case you might conclude there is some repulsive force close to the horizon. But this would just be your interpretation and no general relativist will agree with you.